2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection
Coinciding with your having just graduated, all y'all are scheduled for an election next week, October 16th.In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it here.

Here's how it'll work:

Until the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, October 16th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post one question per answer.
We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of [text](link), as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at currently.
At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. 
Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8). 

How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments? 
How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?



In your opinion, what do moderators do? 
A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that? 
In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep? 


What is the most pressing issue of the Bitcoin Stackexchange and how will you approach it if elected as a moderator?

Given the highly political nature of this space, how would you deal with questions/answers/comments which

Use derogatory terms like Bcash or BScore, SegwitCoin or
BizCoin?
Knowingly/Unknowingly promoting certain client software for bitcoin?


Personally, I would strike/narrow question 2. Nearly all posts promote a certain client. Examples: 1 2 3. Question 1 is very important to having civilized debate.

After looking at the answers of candidates, I think you were right. But, it's too late now

Moderators are called in when something is amiss. When you're elected, a noticeable portion of your time spent on Bitcoin.SE will be evaluating posts that other users flagged for your attention. You'll encounter junk on a daily basis, and on days when you're hard-pressed for time, it may be your only window into the site. Meanwhile, we're asking you to offer patient and diplomatic guidance to the users that tried to contribute. What's your motivation to run for such a job? Why is it important for you to be a moderator? What do you bring to the moderation team to complement your fellow moderators?

Two questions in the same theme:

How did you discover Bitcoin SE?
How can we make contributing to the site more approachable for new users?


I am afraid that the questionnaire was already posted: https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/888/5406

@Murch Whoops. Oh well.
